# linux-mint non-interactive shell start up files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, linux-mint

In Linux-Mint 18, which files are read upon start up of a non-interactive shell?

I'm trying to execute a command via ssh, like

`ssh norio@remote.host.net coolcommand`

but I get an error like 

`bash: coolcommand: command not found`

The file `coolcommand` sits in `/home/norio/bin/`, and 
I set the `PATH` environmental variable to include this directory
in `/home/norio/.bashrc`, and this `.bashrc` is set to be sourced by `/home/norio/.profile` and `/home/norio/.bash_profile`.
But, it doesn't seem any of these files are read when the remote non-interactive shell starts up. In fact, `/etc/profile` doesn't seem to source any of these files. Do I need to edit this file? Or, is there any other way to set up a start-up process for the non-interative shell as a non-root user?

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Comment: Fun fact: `coolcommand` is not `bash`, so it has no job with `~/.bashrc` or any bash-related files.

Comment: @IporSircer Then which shell handles the remote command passed by ssh?

Comment: By default sshd run `bash` after login if you don't specify any command. If you specify a command, then sshd run it **instead of** of bash or any other shells or any other programs. You get what you want: run `coolcommand`

Comment: @IporSircer When I do `ssh remote.host.net ls`, the program `ls` is run without intervention of any shell? How sshd knows the path of `ls`?

Comment: Good question! Ask it on http://unix.stackexchange.com !

Comment: @IporSircer From my research before posting this question, I understood that bash (or another shell set by the system for the user) is invoked as a non-interactive shell when ssh hands over a remtoe command.

Comment: @IporSircer The OpenSSH server launches remote commands (requested by the client) as shell commands using the user's login shell. E.g. if the user's shell is bash, the server launches the equivalent of `bash -c 'the-command'`

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html):

> Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard input connected to a network connection, as when executed by the remote shell daemon, usually rshd, or the secure shell daemon sshd. If Bash determines it is being run in this fashion, it reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists and is readable. It will not do this if invoked as sh. The --norc option may be used to inhibit this behavior, and the --rcfile option may be used to force another file to be read, but neither rshd nor sshd generally invoke the shell with those options or allow them to be specified.